# Tor stuck at start-up

Tags: configuration, torsocks, tor-install, startup

I have been using Tor for while. It was working fine but today it refuses to start. It gets stuck here (at start-up):

```
Apr 29 08:06:14.918 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.0-alpha-dev (git-b6e60f26dd04fa4f) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd N/A.
Apr 29 08:06:14.918 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 29 08:06:14.918 [notice] This version is not a stable Tor release. Expect more bugs than usual.
Apr 29 08:06:14.918 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 29 08:06:14.919 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Apr 29 08:06:14.919 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 08:06:14.919 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 08:06:14.919 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 08:06:14.919 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 08:06:14.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 29 08:06:14.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 29 08:06:15.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Apr 29 08:06:15.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
```

I have tried rebooting and `sudo killall tor` multiple times. Also, I have re installed Tor. I found a similar issue here: [Tor stuck at 0%](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/tor-stuck-at-0) , but no one answered.

```
Apr 29 12:30:13.000 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.0-alpha-dev (git-b6e60f26dd04fa4f) opening new log file.
Apr 29 12:30:13.255 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.0-alpha-dev (git-b6e60f26dd04fa4f) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd N/A.
Apr 29 12:30:13.255 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 29 12:30:13.255 [notice] This version is not a stable Tor release. Expect more bugs than usual.
Apr 29 12:30:13.255 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 29 12:30:13.256 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade $
Apr 29 12:30:13.256 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 12:30:13.256 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 12:30:13.256 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 12:30:13.256 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 12:30:13.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 29 12:30:13.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 29 12:30:13.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Apr 29 12:30:13.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Apr 29 12:30:22.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.0-alpha-dev (git-b6e60f26dd04fa4f) opening log file.
Apr 29 12:31:51.988 [notice] Tor 0.4.4.0-alpha-dev (git-b6e60f26dd04fa4f) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd N/A.
Apr 29 12:31:51.988 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 29 12:31:51.988 [notice] This version is not a stable Tor release. Expect more bugs than usual.
Apr 29 12:31:51.988 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 29 12:31:51.989 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade $
Apr 29 12:31:51.989 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 12:31:51.989 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 29 12:31:51.989 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 12:31:51.989 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [warn] Your log may contain sensitive information - you're logging more than "notice". Don't log unless it serves an important reason. Overwrite the log afterwards.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] options_commit_listener_transaction(): Recomputed OOS thresholds: ConnLimit 1000, ConnLimit_ 4064, ConnLimit_high_thresh 4000, ConnLimit_low_thresh 3048
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] crypto_openssl_late_init(): NOT using OpenSSL engine support.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] evaluate_evp_for_aes(): This version of OpenSSL has a known-good EVP counter-mode implementation. Using it.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] tor_disable_debugger_attach(): Attemping to disable debugger attachment to Tor for unprivileged users.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] tor_lockfile_lock(): Locking "/home/arushiarora/.tor/lock"
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 128.31.0.39:9131 (9695)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 86.59.21.38:80 (847B)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 45.66.33.45:80 (7EA6)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 16 dirserver at 66.111.2.131:9030 (BA44)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 131.188.40.189:80 (F204)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 193.23.244.244:80 (7BE6)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 171.25.193.9:443 (BD6A)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 154.35.175.225:80 (CF6D)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 199.58.81.140:80 (74A9)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] parse_dir_authority_line(): Trusted 100 dirserver at 204.13.164.118:80 (24E2)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] file_status(): stat()ing /home/arushiarora/.tor/state
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] subsystems_register_state_formats(): Added state format for mainloop with index 0
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] or_state_load(): Loaded state from "/home/arushiarora/.tor/state"
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] get_guard_selection_by_name(): Creating a guard selection called default
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] get_guard_selection_by_name(): Creating a guard selection called restricted
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sampled_guards_update_from_consensus(): Not updating the sample guard set; we have no reasonably live consensus.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Akka ($56927E61B51E6F363FB55498150A6DDFCF7077F2): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($ED4BF9F309F002D548F34DB5DEE2ED8D095AE7E6): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($FF3D6D040641D5A33ECC8B2B57D5BC59714C4209): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard albert ($A6931873A2E19FD9109318F430592907D003582F): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard investigator ($288C100FFA656938C23F32207CAF0DA932ECD247): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Protecc ($6A1B4F8A87E327F4E115A385206C0880DB051B3B): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Srv11MuchRelay ($462ECB5FF94C6AB6971E451710B748BE20F7CC8B): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Enterprise ($21EB2176DFD7364A8E3705ABF518E880362425FC): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard brotherhood ($B0A63BC3FDA67A7ADD1BE08BAA8309C4B204D29B): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($088A6237EED87EDEB0E1E3AD0A4A419F963F0787): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard dc6jgk7c ($F0F5074A6DADD3DC22E1FAA18FD6D89CBC52771A): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($B2CB9E5C80367C9026A806EC4801E22425AA7E8A): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard absturztaubetor ($72A33E374DE5AD1E617394896F0FD8B092D3E7C4): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard obiwan ($E81993EA52B73285CFFD02FEC003569D21483001): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard FissionEx3 ($4FDDFAD51B24DDABB62FB59071F4DC421E76C685): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Islay ($F4873B3EC3325B81DC36C7E38AD3A5ED12B2F339): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard tiflin ($74B8B22AF950B0BE11D8A228FB09D2F5279FB757): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($6822B5AE8E9613B8E691870ABC13647C061C3016): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($7A3E534C033E3836BD5AF223B642853C502AB33A): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard taster ($699388030AFC5C110822C85DE97A51545B192987): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard itomori ($861BCFDD148973985E7FE97C7455C9E4AC4E13BE): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard hsjeufh24h7 ($37C1D66559D0C7884E3D21F7DEB58C75D79B98A8): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard chocolaterain ($40CDE936B04B4573A47223396006443CA5EAC845): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($9CC696EDB5806FDF0C4D6E21B723EC4FF3714CA4): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the sample guard set; we have no reasonably live consensus.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [b], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sampled_guards_update_from_consensus(): Not updating the sample guard set; we have no reasonably live consensus.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard UWashingtonCSE ($AE31E0FBF0D3E1B39F1DD8F55BC070D11AF524B0): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard MPtrr1 ($F117B31DF6A73D6F015BCEE4E6AB13474B18A16F): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard bauruine111 ($E2CF09F998248C71139B24B2C92740AEDB1C6D2A): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Init6TorRelay ($A22B1C2EF2255987F8AB8AA0B1A8E23F5023EEB8): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Tor ($60F2139EA3E06410A05CBD6E8254E60A9063AD9D): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($EDF54840C052F226EBDF27D8CB3F8B25E3998DC2): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Stormfront ($AFBE45546DF32BE7914D866D86F44D179E5B1AF0): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard 324partyvan ($91BA193FB362FB7B6679A7A83A3050F3C44A5468): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($D2A056E6321962BD77763FE269E26400A58278F2): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Mudkip ($75983F5660D894FCF2BE452DB35F3E594ADE4B08): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard atoraphobia ($9E43E7D22776AD4534865C9517A5B8962BD39B5D): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard chonk ($4561FC085C3F3A7271FE960317F02DCD1E9C1188): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($DE4F6E528A9FEB1B79BC3D7D24E8BF5BCDEDA0A1): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard myNiceRelay ($872108C52C52CC10217A351C883E991AEDF7C470): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Mowgli ($889944F540C155E7E32C909B9E1424677689AD4D): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard focaltohr ($83AEDBDB4BE3AD0ED91850BF1A521B843077759E): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard BringMeToLife ($343EC037D633150AFFCC8471E805AABAE1B1D871): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard bauruine ($0F7FC8A71C9EB70F497297FDADD1CD3B038C99AB): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard Unnamed ($8C0EFD59A37E2FD9BDCB66A6A35774A4066817EA): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] entry_guard_set_filtered_flags(): Updated sampled guard NeelTorRelayA ($B0F9BA27944FA59E3B1A182208FF7C0CFF5497B2): filtered=0; reachable_filtered=0.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the sample guard set; we have no reasonably live consensus.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [b], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [info] circuit_build_times_parse_state(): Adding 1 timeouts.
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 775
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 425
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 575
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 675
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 625
Apr 29 12:31:51.000 [debug] circuit_build_times_add_time(): Adding circuit build time 525
```

Comment: Have you tried using a bridge, and using a stable version of tor? And if you could post the log messages at info level that may help too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the log file. No I haven't tried using a stable version or a bridge because I have been using Tor for about a year and I never felt the need. Can this be due to my system being on the university network?

Comment: Some universities do block Tor, so that could be it. A bridge should help you connect to the network.

Comment: I tried installing the latest version, but it did not work. Next, I created another account on my NUC and reinstalled tor, it worked fine. Reinstalling tor on my own account did not work though.